# Different child nodes in the same XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

In SQL Server 2008 there is a table with XML column to be queried and there is a need to get the name of the node that is the child of the "Inc" node - in the example below "Architect" and "Professor". We do not know all of the child nodes (Professor, Architect, etc.) so we cannot just outer apply all of the potential child nodes names, but we need to extract their values for every row.
First row:

```
  <Inc>
    <Architect>
        <ArchitectLevel>
          <Average>100000</Average>
        </ArchitectLevel>
    </Architect>
  </Inc>
```

Second row:

```
    <Inc>
        <Professor>
            <ProfessorLevel>
                <Maximum>100000</Maximum>
                <Minimum>1000</Minimum>
            </ProfessorLevel>
        </Professor>
    </Inc>
```

Does someone now how to do it?

Comment: Can you show the expected result for both the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `local-name()` Demo

```
declare @x xml =
'<Inc>
  <Architect>
        <ArchitectLevel>
          <Average>100000</Average>
        </ArchitectLevel>
    </Architect>
</Inc>
<Inc>
    <Professor>
        <ProfessorLevel>
            <Maximum>100000</Maximum>
            <Minimum>1000</Minimum>
        </ProfessorLevel>
    </Professor>
</Inc>';

select t.n.value('local-name(.)[1]','varchar(100)')
from @x.nodes('Inc/*') t(n)
```

Comment: Thanks @Serg. Is there a way to select only the first child node's name? For example, if there is <Professor>, <Professor2> and <Professor3> inside <Inc>, we would only choose <Professor> ? Your solution lists all of them.

Comment: What is the rule to parse node's name exactly? Why 'Professor' and 'Professor2' should be considered equal?

Comment: @user3853657 It might be enough to use a `[1]` predicate in `.nodes()` like here: `from @x.nodes('Inc/*[1]') t(n)`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted, @Shnugo . I tried to use [1] without a * and it did not work.